Primes of the form $F(a^{k+1})/F(a^k)$
Letting $F(n)$ be the $n$'th Fibonacci number, for what $a$ and $k\ge 1$ is $F(a^{k+1})/F(a^k)$ prime?
I know of just $6$ examples:
$$\eqalign{
3 &= F(2^2)/F(2^1)\cr
7 &= F(2^3)/F(2^2)\cr
17 &= F(3^2)/F(3^1)\cr
47 &= F(2^4)/F(2^3)\cr
2207 &= F(2^5)/F(2^4)\cr
97415813466381445596089 &= F(11^2)/F(11^1)\cr}$$
If it exists, any other example is greater than $10^{20000}$.
It's easy to show that $a$ must be prime.
EDIT: A similar question can be asked about Lucas numbers, where we need $a$ to be odd.  The only examples I have found are:
$$\eqalign{19 &=L(3^2)/L(3^1)\cr
5779 &=L(3^3)/L(3^2)\cr
599786069 &=L(7^2)/L(7^1)\cr
97420733208491869044199 &=L(11^2)/L(11^1)
}$$

See OEIS sequence A371866.
